# When setting MySQL schema, why use certain types?

Tags: mysql, database

When I'm setting up a MySQL table, it asks me to define the name of the column, type of input, and length. My assumption, without having read anything about it, is that it's for minimization. Specify the smallest possible int/smallint/tinyint for your needs, and it will reduce overhead of some sort. If it's all positives, make it unsigned to double your space, etc.

What happens if I just make every field a varchar-200 characters? When/why is this bad, what will I miss out on, and when will any inefficiencies manifest themselves? 100k records?

I think about this every time I set up a DB, but I haven't built anything to scale enough where I've ever had my scheme setup inappropriately, either too "strict/small" or "loose/big". Can someone confirm that I'm making good assumptions about speed and efficiency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data types not only optimize storage, but how data is indexed. As your databases get bigger, it will become apparent that it's quicker to search for all the records that have a 1 in an integer field than those that have a "1" in a varchar field. This becomes especially important when you're joining data from more than one table and your database engine is having to do this sort of thing repeatedly. (Daren also rightly points out below that it's important that the types of the fields you're matching on are identical as well.)

The level at which these inefficiencies become an issue depends greatly on your hardware and your application design. We have big enough iron these days that if you're building moderate-scale apps, you may not see an appreciable difference. (Aside from feeling a little bit guilty about your database design!) But establishing good habits on small projects makes the bigger ones easier when they come along.

Comment: I'd like to add when changing the field length and types used for table joins, ensure you always change them in both places.  Table joins on non identical indicies is almost as slow as no index at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two columns as varchar and put in the values 10 and 20 and add them, you'll get 1020 instead of 30 which you'd likely expect.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could save everything as VARCHAR strings. But you'd be giving up a lot of functionality provided by the database engine.

You should choose the database type that most closely matches the intended use of the column. For example, using DATE or DATETIME to store dates provides you with all sorts of date/time functions that you don't get with basic VARCHAR types.

Likewise, fields used to count things or provide simple unique IDs should be INT or one of its related types. Also bear in mind that an INT occupies only 4 bytes, whereas a 9-digit string uses at least 9 bytes.

For character data, it's wise to use NVARCHAR for internationalized values that users in any locale are going to enter (esp. names and locations). If you know the text is limited to US or internal use only, VARCHAR is safe.